# You are too/ very kind to me

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence

> **You  are  too kind  to  me.**
>
> **You  are  very  kind  to  me**

I  have  found the  entry   **You  are  too kind  to  me** in  Michael  Swan' s  Practical English  Usage. But  it  was  not  explained   when  it  was  used.But  it  was  said  that  **You  are too much  kind  to  me**  is  wrong.

I think *too  kind*  connotates  some  negative  interpretation  and  *very  kind*  is  used  is  to  express  thanks  or  gratitude.

I  would  like  to  know  the  contexts where  *you  are  very  kind*  and   *you  are  too  kind  are  used.*

What  is the  difference  between  *you  are  too kind*  and  *you  are very  kind?*

Comment: In which aspect of grammar did the sentence occur? What is it exemplifying and what other examples of the same structure does Swan give?

Comment: I  think  the only thing  some  users do  is  either to go in for  negative  voting or  vote  for  closing.

Comment: I neither downvoted nor voted to close your question. I have Swan's book and was interested to know the context in which the sentence occurred. _You are too kind to me_ can be interpreted literally or  (more likely) as heartfelt thanks. It needs context to disambiguate.

Comment: Do please stop whinging about down-votes. _Everyone_ gets them. Not to mention you are 2+ right now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, 'You are too kind' does not have a negative implication. It's a rather exaggerated way of thanking someone, suggesting that they are showing you more kindness than you deserve.

Comment: The negative connotations all rise from the context: when there's not really a reason to be all that grateful, the stronger the expression, the more (intentionally) insincere it feels. But there certainly are many cases where it is perfectly appropriate to use this exact phrase.

Comment: In my experience it is used, more often than not, with a touch of sarcasm.

Comment: I do not know how a question with four good answers  can be offtopic.The ways of the site are mysterious and misleading.I stopped asking or answering questions on all thses sites two months ago.I am really fed up with the behaviour of the users  and even the moderators.I do not mind whether the question is closed or kept open

Answer (score 4):

'You are too kind' is merely an idiom. In normal conversation, it doesn't convey any sort of negative connotation - but it can be (and is!) used sarcastically or as a form of flattery, which is where that negative connotation would arise.

'You are very kind' is similar in its meaning but seems more effusive and heartfelt (though that is my personal opinion on the matter).

I'm sure there are regional differences in how often they crop up, but their underlying meaning is the same. Therefore, they can both be suited to a wide range of situations - it depends on your personal preference for one or the other.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the difference between you are too kind and you are very kind?

**too kind**  [MacMillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/you-re-too-kind-generous)

> used for thanking someone in a way that is very polite but **not**
>   completely sincere

And from [**You're Too Kind -
A Brief History of Flattery**
By RICHARD STENGEL](https://archive.nytimes.com/www.nytimes.com/books/first/s/stengel-kind.html), we can again find some negative connotation. Depending on the context, of course.  The article is a fascinating read and somewhat a narrative etymology of self love and flattery.

> That ironic tone is so often the cloak for all flattery, indeed all
>   praise, these days. What we think of as flattery is usually delivered
>   with an air of arch knowingness, a kind of self-consciousness that
>   says, We all know this is flattery, so don't consider me a weaselly
>   little brownnose for saying it. In fact, these days we struggle to
>   invent new ways to praise people because the traditional methods are
>   seen as a worn-out currency.

This leaves the other compliments such as **kind** and **very kind** to their literal meanings, stripped bare of most other connotations.  Of course, context is critical in perceiving the meaning of 'too kind' and 'very kind'.

Comment: Well researched! Good job.

Answer (score 1):

(British English speaker here)

I would say both are the same meaning, except that "too kind" is a little more formal, and, as such, maybe slightly prone to being misinterpreted as insincere if you do not normally talk in that manner.  However either can be used with the same meaning, and if accompanied with a smile then there should be little chance of misinterpretation.